# I cannot call methods in c#

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

I picked up a project recently...

I cannot call methods in C #.

Did some setting in Visual Studio? I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Look my code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Web.Classes;

namespace Web.Business
{
    public class TicketDB
    {


        Random r = new Random();

        r.Next(4); // Error 

    }  
}
```

Comment: You forgot using System.Random or something.

Comment: I removed... No work. My error in Error list -> 3          Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: You should read and learn more over c# and OOP. What is written here does not make sense.

Comment: #Mecek, thanks for touch. It was distracting me ... Am I the only staff member who works with. Net ... Sometimes we do not see things simple.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define a method first. Just a class is not enough.

Here is an example with a `Main()` method, but you can use another method (or even constructor) as well:

```
private static void Main()
{
  Random r = new Random();
  r.Next(4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Class code should more be like that:

```
public class TicketDB
{
  int rNum = 0;

  // Constructor - called when created
  public TicketDB()
  {
    Random r = new Random();
    rNum = r.Next(4); // Error 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could. I was forgetting to call within the method. My fault.
Thanks for the help. Helped me remember the OOP.